# What is the correct way to write the word "back-end"?

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

Back-end and front-end are common technical terms nowadays. Traditionally, they are written with a hyphen "back-end". Is there a rule in the English language that dictates this to be a correct way to write term, that signifies general single something? Or did it just "stick" that way?

**Clarification 1:**
The proposed answer that discusses when to hyphenate assumes back-end as a compound word. I don't think it is and this am asking this question. Compound words like on-the-fly are comprised of possible standalone words that are all required to describe the phenomenon or thing in question.

Backend is a synonym to server-side, which really is a compound word. Backend is a singularization of server-side, not a compound itself.

I understand that I may have a logical "gap" somewhere in this line, the reason why I asked is to help me clarify this.

Comment: There is never almost any logic to whether compound words should be hyphenated or not.

Comment: Can you please explain why you think it isn't a compound word?

Comment: @curiousdannii updated the question to try to explain my line of thinking about this.

Comment: Most styleguides recommend that you hyphenate phrases when using them as modifiers ("The back-end subsystem"; "on-the-fly calculation") but not when they are stand alone ("The back end"'; "do it on the fly"). I would not write _backend_ as one word, but I wouldn't be surprised to see it.

Comment: In general, the more familiar one is with the term the more apt one is to write it as a single compound word.  Thus computer geeks will write of "backend optimization", since it's a term they're apt to use quite often (in certain circles).

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=backend%2Cback+end%2Cback-end&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbackend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cback%20end%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cback%20-%20end%3B%2Cc0) suggest that *back-end* and *backend* have increased in popularity recently